# Laravel pluck values from database and push into an existing array

Tags: php, laravel

I have an existing array which looks like below

```
 $existingArray = [
      'email'           => $user->email, 
      'name'            => $name,
      'Firstname'       => $firstname ]
```

Then I pluck some values from the database

```
$plucked = CustomAnswer::where('id','=',5)->pluck('model', 'make'); //which should return ['Fiat'=>'Punto']
```

What I would like to do is to inject the plucked array into the existing array such that I have

```
$newArray = [
      'email'           => $user->email, 
      'name'            => $name,
      'Firstname'       => $firstname, 
      'Fiat'            => Punto]
```

I am fully aware that the array_push method does not work on associative arrays, are their other things that I can try to achieve this?

Comment: `$existingArray['Fiat'] = ... ` ?

Comment: Okay but example, I won't always know what value is stored in plucked so effetcively the key is dynamic, it can be anything..

Comment: Im not sure what you're trying to do. But you're able to use a variable in that syntax like `$existingArray[$key] = '...'`.

Answer (score 2):

try [`array_merge()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
$newArray = array_merge($existingArray,$plucked);
```